# uitableview crashed when scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i am developing an app with the help of [this](https://github.com/aberger/ABMExpandingTableViewCells) example in my app and everything is working as required but when i expand the expended cell and scroll down app crashes when table reaches at the end. let me post all my code here.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        FSParallaxTableViewCell *cell = nil;
        static NSString *cellIdentifier = nil;
        // init expanded cell
        if ([indexPath isEqual:self.expandedIndexPath]) {
            cellIdentifier = @"ExpandedCellIdentifier";
        }
        // init expanding cell
        else {
            cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        }
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[FSParallaxTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
            cell.cellImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"];
        }
        if ([[cell reuseIdentifier] isEqualToString:@"ExpandedCellIdentifier"]) {
    cell.playIconBig = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            cell.playIconBig.tag= indexPath.row-1;
            [cell.playIconBig addTarget:self action:@selector(play:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
            cell.playIconBig.frame = CGRectMake(25, 5, 25, 25);
            [cell.playIconBig setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play_expand.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.playIconBig];
    }
        // set text in expanding cell
        if ([[cell reuseIdentifier] isEqualToString:@"Cell"]) {
            [cell.cellImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]xmllink]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"] options:indexPath.row == 0 ? SDWebImageRefreshCached : 0];
            cell.clipsToBounds = YES;

            //[cell.contentView addSubview:arrowImg];

            cell.song.text = [[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]xmltitle];
            cell.artist.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"By %@",[[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]xmlsinger]];
            cell.share.text = [[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]xmllikes];
            cell.download.text = [[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]xmldownloads];
    }
// set text in expanding cell
if ([[cell reuseIdentifier] isEqualToString:@"Cell"]) {
    [cell.cellImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]xmllink]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"] options:indexPath.row == 0 ? SDWebImageRefreshCached : 0];
    cell.clipsToBounds = YES;

    //[cell.contentView addSubview:arrowImg];

    cell.song.text = [[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]xmltitle];
    cell.artist.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"By %@",[[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]xmlsinger]];
}
        return cell;
    }

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // take expanded cell into account when returning number of rows
    if (self.expandedIndexPath) {
        return [rssOutputData count] + 1;
    }
    return [rssOutputData count];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if ([indexPath isEqual:self.expandedIndexPath])
    {
        return 40;//height for expanded
    } else {
        return 140;//height for normal
    }
}
```

and here didselectrowatindexpath method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.view addSubview:_internetConnectionIndicator];
    // disable touch on expanded cell
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([[cell reuseIdentifier] isEqualToString:@"ExpandedCellIdentifier"]) {
        return;
    }

    // deselect row
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                             animated:NO];
    // get the actual index path
    indexPath = [self actualIndexPathForTappedIndexPath:indexPath];
    // save the expanded cell to delete it later
    NSIndexPath *theExpandedIndexPath = self.expandedIndexPath;
    // same row tapped twice - get rid of the expanded cell
    if ([indexPath isEqual:self.expandingIndexPath]) {
        self.expandingIndexPath = nil;
        self.expandedIndexPath = nil;
    }
    // add the expanded cell
    else {
        self.expandingIndexPath = indexPath;
        self.expandedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[indexPath row] + 1
                                                    inSection:[indexPath section]];
    }

    [tableView beginUpdates];

    if (theExpandedIndexPath) {
        [theTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[theExpandedIndexPath]
                            withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    }
    if (self.expandedIndexPath) {
        [theTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[self.expandedIndexPath]
                            withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    }

    [tableView endUpdates];

    // scroll to the expanded cell
    [self.theTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                             atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle
                                     animated:YES];
}
- (NSIndexPath *)actualIndexPathForTappedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (self.expandedIndexPath && [indexPath row] > [self.expandedIndexPath row]) {
        return [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[indexPath row] - 1
                                  inSection:[indexPath section]];
    }

    return indexPath;
}

#pragma mark - UIScrollViewdelegate methods

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    for (FSParallaxTableViewCell *cell in self.theTableView.visibleCells) {
        [self updateImageViewCellOffset:cell];
    }
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self updateImageViewCellOffset:(FSParallaxTableViewCell *)cell];
}
```

Please help me debugging my code. Thanks here is error msg

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 6 beyond bounds [0 .. 5]'
```

Comment: remove all breakpoints and go to `breakpoint navigator(left tab of xcode->2nd last option), click "all exceptions at the bottom"` and run the app, you will get the exact line of crash. The error is just `array out of bounds exception`, your code is trying to fetch an element in the array whose index is not there in array.

Comment: tried this but have same exception error. thanks

Comment: yes the exception will be same but you will get to know which line is causing the error :) , did you get the line causing the error? which line of code it is? Please share

Comment: Show the exception stack trace.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 6 beyond bounds [0 .. 5]'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: having error on this line [cell.cellImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]xmllink]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"] options:indexPath.row == 0 ? SDWebImageRefreshCached : 0];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        FSParallaxTableViewCell *cell = nil;
        static NSString *cellIdentifier = nil;
        // init expanded cell
        if (indexPath.row >= [rssOutputData count])
            cellIdentifier = @"ExpandedCellIdentifier";
        }
        // init expanding cell
        else {
            cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        }
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[FSParallaxTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
            cell.cellImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"];
        }
        if (indexPath.row >= [rssOutputData count]){
    cell.playIconBig = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            cell.playIconBig.tag= indexPath.row-1;
            [cell.playIconBig addTarget:self action:@selector(play:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
            cell.playIconBig.frame = CGRectMake(25, 5, 25, 25);
            [cell.playIconBig setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play_expand.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.playIconBig];
    }else {
            [cell.cellImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]xmllink]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"] options:indexPath.row == 0 ? SDWebImageRefreshCached : 0];
            cell.clipsToBounds = YES;

            //[cell.contentView addSubview:arrowImg];

            cell.song.text = [[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]xmltitle];
            cell.artist.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"By %@",[[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]xmlsinger]];
            cell.share.text = [[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]xmllikes];
            cell.download.text = [[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]xmldownloads];
    }
        return cell;
    }

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // take expanded cell into account when returning number of rows
    if (self.expandedIndexPath) {
        return [rssOutputData count] + 1;
    }
    return [rssOutputData count];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if ([indexPath isEqual:self.expandedIndexPath])
    {
        return 40;//height for expanded
    } else {
        return 140;//height for normal
    }
}
```

Comment: The crash is due to the retrieval of an array item from out of the array bounds. that means,the condition if ([indexPath isEqual:self.expandedIndexPath]) may not be working. so just changed the checking condition..

Comment: thanks Neenu please review my question i updated cellForRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite sure that the method `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` returns the wrong number, it returns the number that bigger than the data size. Please check carefully these lines of code:

```
if (self.expandedIndexPath) {
    return [rssOutputData count] + 1;
}
```

Assure that the condition of the if statement is correct. There is a case that you have modified the data else where but you don't know about that.

Comment: yes i know that but thing is that i need that expandedindexpath but is it possible that i can change count when i start scrolling while table is expanded and close it! any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

If you are returning number of rows after adding +1 to the data source than

```
if (self.expandedIndexPath) {
    return [rssOutputData count] + 1;
}
```

you should ensure that for the additional row you should not access the modal / rssOutputData should be accessed till it bounds. If in case some how the code accesses the rssOutputData for the index for which the data doesn't exist than you should be ready to see error as below

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 6 beyond bounds [0 .. 5]'
```

Please re manipulate your code it's somehow trying to access the array out of bounds.

Comment: Thanks but i already know all this i just want to know how can i solve this issue.